# Quaternion, Dihedral groups and A-D-E classification

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

$\bullet$ What is the role of Quaternion group $H$ and dihedral groups $D_n$ in [A-D-E classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADE_classification)?

$\bullet$ Is Quaternion group $H$ in $A$ (special linear Lie algebra of traceless operators) or not?

$\bullet$ Is dihedral group $D_n$ in $D$ (even special orthogonal Lie algebra of even dimensional skew-symmetric operators) or not?